# Calculating the longest path length in drainage network using Python

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, network, length

I have a drainage network and I want to obtain the longest path length between two coordinates of the shapefile; is there is a way to automate this process in Python?

For example, in the image, I want to get the green path from the black drainage network and calculate the length of this.

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226052/is-there-an-optimal-algorithm-to-find-the-longest-shortest-path-in-a-network

Comment: Explore python module `networkx`.